# Nested dictionaries and multi-processing

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

I have a dictionary of authors and each author is a dictionary of books and each book is a list of words.

I need a multiprocessing scenario where each process deals with a certain book from a certain author.

I tried using `manager.dict()` and `manager.list()` for instantiating the dicts and the lists but my dictionary is still not getting populated.

This is how the main dictionary object is declared.

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import  Manager

manager = Manager()
allWords = manager.dict()
```

Then there's a function `read_author` which does the task distribtion

```
def read_author(author):
        global allWords
        allWords[author] = manager.dict() # each author is a dictionary of books
        jobs = []
        for f in os.listdir(auth_dir):
                p = multiprocessing.Process(target=read_doc, args=(author, auth_dir, f,)) 
                jobs.append(p)
                p.start()
        return jobs
```

And this is the function that makes my processes.

```
def read_doc(author_name, author_dir, doc_name):
        global allWords
        allWords[author_name][doc_name] = manager.list()
        # document is loaded in the variable doc and it has a set of words
        for word in doc.words:
            allWords[author_name][doc_name].append(word)
```

Documents are txt files from project Gutenberg and the `doc` object above is a syntax tree constructed using `spacy`.

The `read_doc` actually involves document tree parsing and extraction and counting of bigrams. I skipped those parts in the code sample for brevity but it is the counting task that I want to split over multiple CPU cores and that's why I'm using multiprocessing.

Comment: Where's your code ?

Comment: Try writing up a [MCVE] that shows the problem you're running into

Comment: @PedroLobito  I added some code. Could you please have another look.

Comment: Please update your code so that we know what your XML looks like, how you're getting it (a rough description at least) and explain what you explained to me in the comments below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python multiprocessing guidelines suggest to avoid shared state as far as possible.
While it's not quite clear to me why your code doesn't work,
I do not see any reason to use `Manager` and shared state.
In this sample the final `allWords` dict is assembled in the main process from the word lists generated in `Pool` processes:

```
def read_doc(author_name, doc_name):
    # document is loaded in the variable doc and it has a set of words
    return author_name, doc_name, list(doc.words)

def read_doc_param_gen(authors):
    for author in authors:
        auth_dir =  deduce_auth_dir(author)
        for f in os.listdir(auth_dir):
            yield author, f

def read_authors(authors):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    allWords = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    for author_name, doc_name, lst in pool.map(read_doc, read_doc_param_gen(authors)):
        allWords[author_name][doc_name] = lst
    return allWords
```

There is also `Pool.imap` if you need to update some GUI or stuff.